# Is there a way to distribute an IOS app for around 500 users for free (without developer account)?

Tags: ios, react-native, ios-provisioning, iosdeployment

There are some apps that can be installed from safari and by trusting the developer . Now , The app isn't available on App Store, But still i can use it without reinstalling the certificate in a week .
I want a permanent solution for this so that i can distribute my MESS MENU APP for my Hostel . It is simple and small and hence i dont feel like putting it on appstore since its inhouse only . Any Suggestions are welcome

Comment: Hi Borda. Have you search for "iOS AppStore alternative" in a search engine?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: @Meet Borda You need to have  Enrolled account to do that.

Comment: I am not talking about alternatives , i have used some apps that i installed from safari . I just want to build an ipa that i can distribute in my hostel

Comment: It sounds like this might be better developed as a responsive web site.  Then there is no need to install any app.  There isn't really an app distribution method that is applicable for your app; Possibly you could put it in the App Store, but Apple may reject it as being for a limited audience.  You can't use Enterprise or B2B apps because the devices are presumably personal, not corporate owned.,

Comment: Exactly @Paulw11 , the reason i need it to be an app is that there is an android app that is being used since 4-5 years , People are used to using the app . I would strongly like it to be an app because its too convenient .

Comment: The only way to distribute apps to a wide range of devices that aren't company owned or managed is by joining the developer program and distributing via the App Store; There is a risk, however, that Apple won't approve your app as it has limited functionality and a limited audience.  You can create a web app and include instructions on adding the shortcut to the device home screen.